# jquery toggle() triggers unwanted animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle, slidetoggle

i have this simple function:

```
$('.tools-dropdown-launch').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.tools-dropdown-content').toggle(function () {
        fixPanelHeight();
    });
});
```

which should toggle visibility of another div but with **no animations**. Instead I have a similar `slideToggle()` type of animation. the function triggered is the following:

```
function fixPanelHeight() {
    var maxPanelHeight = 0;
    $(".inner-menu-panel-containter").children(".menu-panel").each(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        element.css("height", "auto");
        if (element.height() > maxPanelHeight) {
            maxPanelHeight = element.height();
        }
    })
    if (maxPanelHeight > 0) {
        $(".inner-menu-panel-containter").children(".menu-panel").height(maxPanelHeight);
    }
}
```

i tried changing the first function to

```
$('.tools-dropdown-launch').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.tools-dropdown-content').toggle();
});
```

and it works as expected: i have no animations BUT the function (of course) isn't triggering.

why is this happening?

There's no height transitions in the css and there's no `slideToggle()` anywhere in the js file.

this is solved with

```
$('.tools-dropdown-content').slideToggle(0 , function () {
        fixPanelHeight();
    });
```

but I would prefer something better then this quickfix.

Comment: Passing complete callback function to jq [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method implecitely calls animation using default duration (400ms). Now, it isn't clear what is your expected behaviour? What's wrong with just using `toggle()`?

Comment: i expect not to have an animation as I'm using toggle() and not slideToggle() in my function. is there a way to avoid this.. i need to toggle display:none/block with no special effect, transition or animation

Comment: But i'm still not sure why cannot you just use `.toggle()`? It won't use any animation. And because then it is sync, you can just use: `$('.tools-dropdown-content').toggle(); fixPanelHeight();`

Comment: Won't `toggle(0, function(){})` work or am I missing something ?

Comment: @A.Wolff i **am** using toggle() :) that's why it surprises me it's animating

Comment: @Chintan Ya it would work

Comment: @vlrprbttst But the doc is clear enough. `toggle()` can be used to animate element(s): `When a duration, a plain object, or a single "complete" function is provided, .toggle() becomes an animation method. The .toggle() method animates the width, height, and opacity of the matched elements simultaneously. When these properties reach 0 after a hiding animation, the display style property is set to none to ensure that the element no longer affects the layout of the page.`

Comment: @A.Wolff now I know it :) i thought that if i wanted an animation i should have used slideToggle()

Answer (score -1):

```
 $("#show_advance").click(function () {
            //  $(".ad_search").slideToggle("slow");
            if ($(".ad_search").is(':hidden')) {
                $('.advance_search').text('hide Advance Search');
                $(".ad_search").slideToggle("slow");
            }
            else {
                $('.advance_search').text('Show Advance Search');
                $(".ad_search").slideToggle("slow");
            }
        });
```

Use This May be Helpfull for you.